# Eclipse Warning When I try to run a GAE project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Am using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver) as a reference so that I can be able run a GAE project locally. Am using the Google Plugin for eclipse.

When I click the button Run, i get WARNINGS in the console.

> objc[1622]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> -server must be followed by an argument for servletContainerLauncher[:args] Google Web Toolkit 2.6.0 DevMode
>   [-[no]startServer] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist
>   whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory]
>   [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address]
>   [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-server
>   servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy
>   dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] [-sourceLevel [auto, 1.6, 1.7]]
>   module[s]

and

> where    -[no]startServer  Starts a servlet container serving the
>   directory specified by the -war flag. (defaults to ON)   -port
>   Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888) 
>   -whitelist        Allows the user to browse URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)   -blacklist
>   Prevents the user browsing URLs that match the specified regexes
>   (comma or space separated)   -logdir           Logs to a file in the
>   given directory, as well as graphically   -logLevel         The level
>   of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
>   -gen              Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory   -bindAddress      Specifies
>   the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to
>   127.0.0.1)   -codeServerPort   Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997)   -server           Specify a different
>   embedded web server to run (must implement ServletContainerLauncher)
>   -startupUrl       Automatically launches the specified URL   -war              The directory into which deployable output files will be written
>   (defaults to 'war')   -deploy           The directory into which
>   deployable but not servable output files will be written (defaults to
>   'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war directory/jar, and may be the same as
>   the -extra directory/jar)   -extra            The directory into which
>   extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written   -workDir
>   The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable;
>   defaults to a system temp dir)   -sourceLevel      Specifies Java
>   source level (defaults to auto:1.7) and    module[s]         Specifies
>   the name(s) of the module(s) to host

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to be able to launch GAE project offline using the terminal  but I can't because of the above errors, what could be the problem?

Comment: I think @Hasan has given you quite a good answer. Could you  comment or accept it?

Comment: @MarCialR  -- Thanks for giving this a kick.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much clarity from you about your set up I can see that you need to clean up your  Java installation.

It is complaining about finding a choice between two possibly different, but probably identical, classes called "JavaLaunchHelper".

You have one here :

```
{JAVAHOME}/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

You have another one here :

```
{JAVAHOME}/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
```

I *believe* it is also hinting that you fix it in the command line you use to launch Eclipse.

> -server must be followed by an argument for servletContainerLauncher[:args]

If I were you I would try renaming the first of the two options **temporarily**, from ...

```
{JAVAHOME}/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

... TO ...

```
{JAVAHOME}/Contents/Home/binTEMP/java
```

Suck it and see, as they say in England.  That *might* get you going, while borking up a whole bunch of other things.

Really, you need to read up on JAVA_HOME, JAVA_PATH and JavaLaunchHelper and how they must be prepared for your operating system.  Having JRE and JDK both in your path can lead to all kinds of confusing behaviour.